# Fusion drive: replace SSD and HDD vice-versa

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, fusion-drive

I've just made a Fusion Drive on my MBP 2012 and restored data from the Time Machine. Unfortunately, right now I read information that the best place for SSD is the main bay of HDD not the optical bay. So I want to replace SSD to the main bay and HDD to the optical bay.

My question is: it's possible without reinstalling the system?

I'm asking because I not fully understand how Fusion Drive works. When I make coreStorage and I put the names of disks (For instance, `/dev/disk0` and `/dev/disk1`) how it determines where is the SSD and where is the HDD? By manufacture information? So it means that I can replace SSD and HDD vice-versa and it's gonna be fine or coreStorage stores information about each drive how it was determine: first - SSD - `/dev/disk0`, second - HDD - `/dev/disk1`?

Comment: Try it and if it doesn't work you can always switch them back

Comment: How about some links to where read the information. If everything is working OK, then the only reason I can think of for switching would be if you are not getting the full 6 Gb/sec transfer rate. So what is the transfer rate to/from your SSD? Do you know how to determine this?

Answer (score 1):

I did the trick by Trent Fitzpatrick's recommendation. Everything works. Speed doesn't changed. Probably it's because I've just made a Fusion Drive and there need some time, probably it doesn't affect at all. But Write 120mb/s and Read 380 mb/s really slow for Fusion Drive I guess.

I'll wait some time and if speed doesn't will change I guess I'll replace SSD and HDD again because HDD tray has some shock protection.